# iOS 10 how to make status bar keep portrait?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar, landscape

I want make all ViewController stay portrait except video player controller. So I made a custom navigator extended by UINavigationController.

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
        return .portrait
    }

}
```

All is OK but status bar still rotate to landscape like this:
[image]

Anyone can help me about this? Thanks a lot and swift code will better for me.

Comment: your overriden shouldAutorotate is causing this. You should override it to return true only for your VidePlayer Controller

Comment: @noir_eagle I remove it from NavigationController but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by delete UIMainStoryboardFile in info.plist. By the way,I don't use storyboard so I add navigation controller by

```
self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
let a = ViewController()
let nav = PumpNavigationController.init(rootViewController: a)
self.window?.rootViewController = nav
```